# How to check how many buttons have been clicked in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, button, radio-button

I am trying to make an attendance page with html radio buttons. So when i submit it, I want it to return how many radio buttons with title as present are checked and how many radio buttons with title as absent ae checked.

> Extra info: I am using Mac OS X El Capitan, Bootstrap and tomcat for localhost and java for backend support

Please suggest answers with **javascript only**

## HTML

```
<label>Present<input type="radio" name="optradio" class="radiobtn" onclick =" // please help "></label>

<label>Absent<input type="radio" name="optradio" class="radiobtn" onclick =" // please help "></label>
```

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: Start here: `[...document.querySelectorAll("[type=radio]:checked")].forEach((rad) => { push to array })` I would give the radios a class of present and absent too

Comment: Make sure to set name and value correctly: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

Answer (score 1):

Use `querySelectorAll('.present:checked')` to select all the elements that are checked and have the class present. You can then get the length of the returned node list.

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  let present = document.querySelectorAll('.present:checked').length
  let absent = document.querySelectorAll('.absent:checked').length
  
  console.clear()
  console.log('present:', present)
  console.log('absent:', absent)
})
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Billy</td>
      <td><label>Present<input type="radio" name="optradio[1]" class="radiobtn present"></label></td>
      <td><label>Absent<input type="radio" name="optradio[1]" class="radiobtn absent"></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bobby</td>
      <td><label>Present<input type="radio" name="optradio[2]" class="radiobtn present"></label></td>
      <td><label>Absent<input type="radio" name="optradio[2]" class="radiobtn absent"></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Joey</td>
      <td><label>Present<input type="radio" name="optradio[3]" class="radiobtn present"></label></td>
      <td><label>Absent<input type="radio" name="optradio[3]" class="radiobtn absent"></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Samantha</td>
      <td><label>Present<input type="radio" name="optradio[4]" class="radiobtn present"></label></td>
      <td><label>Absent<input type="radio" name="optradio[4]" class="radiobtn absent"></label></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks its working but i need to display the result